# How do I run expo app after publishing in expo 48.0.0

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a React Native expo app and I ran it and published it, after publishing the app and running the app url link generated by expo, it only displayed the app SplahScreen and started complaining of expo upgrade that I used expo 43.0.0 and it's not compactible with the Expo Go app version and I did the upgrade and published again but i got "sdkVersion" error while trying to publish to expo. I got frustrated and created a new fresh react native expo with updated expo version XMRthe fresh updated react native expo to investigate what the error was. I published it and everything was fine but expo published it(as an update to the previous XMR I clicked on the new generated link it would only open my expo url account and displayed the app properties but not running the real app on the device like it did on previous 43.0.0 publish. I later realised the new published expo created two updates which are ioS and andorid and when I opened the iOS update it prompted me to scan a QRCode to run the app and upon using an Expo Go app on iPhone to scan, the app tried to run but showed the following error

```
No project found at exp://exp.host/@accountname/project

exp://exp.host/@accountname/project
```

I have a question please, do I need to create a build after publishing in expo? I only wanted to be able to share the work in progress of the app with my development team and client and I believe expo publish would automatically do that after publishing the app to expo but it is not working as expected. What am I missing please? I even tried to delete the app on Expo platform and publish a new one but I didn't even see how to delete on expo platform.

When I try to run the app on android emulator on my computer by using "expo start", i would get the following error when I used "expo start" :

Error: Cannot find module 'metro-core'

After exploring the internet for the error, i got help to run it with "npx expo start", i did and it started the build and generated a scan code, i scanned the code from my android and ios phone but they couldn't run. On iPhone I got the error below :

```
There was a problem loading the requested app.

Could not connect to the server. exp://127.0.0.1:19000
```

On android, when i would get a blue screen with the error below :

```
Something went wrong.

Sorry about that. You can go back to Expo home or try to reload the project.
```

I will appreciate some helpful guides.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should start an app with `npx expo start` command instead of **deprecated** `expo start`. Also assuming you have upgraded from expo 43, you should remove expo-cli package and install it globally using `npm i -g expo-cli`

Comment: I have done the upgrade and install expo cli globally. I can run the application now but I need to do expo publish so that I can send the app for view to my collaboration team. After publishing to expo, do I need to build again in expo website or publishing to expo alone and getting the link generated by expo after publishing is all I need? And how do I delete the previous publish in my expo account?